# Get row value in foreach in laravel view from query

Tags: laravel-5

I have to get the subject name of every row for the query newsubject =  " ". the query required 4 parameters and 3 have been provided by an input. The subject is to be obtained from the view row. i want to be able to obtained the rank to subject with a class of student with certain academic year and programme

```
$getProgramme = Input::get('getProgramme');
    $getYear = Input::get('getYear');
    $getTerm = Input::get('getTerm');
    $getLevel = Input::get('getLevel');

    $getResults = DB::table('resultsView')
        ->leftjoin(DB::raw('((SELECT sregNumber1, scorelevel1,term_Desc1,term_Year1, newsubject,prog1,
        CASE WHEN @prevRank = total_score1 THEN @curRank WHEN @prevRank := total_score1 THEN @curRank := @curRank + 1 END AS subject_ranked FROM scorebysubject q,
                          (SELECT @curRank :=0, @prevRank := NULL) r where prog1 ="' . $getProgramme . '" and  `scorelevel1` = "' . $getLevel . '" and term_Desc1 = "' . $getTerm . '"
                          and term_Year1 = "' . $getYear . '" and newsubject =  " " ORDER BY total_score1 Desc) as t3 )'), function ($join) {
            $join->on('sregNumber1', '=', 'regNumber')
                ->on('newsubject', '=', 'subject')
                ->on('term_Desc1', '=', 'termDesc')
                ->on('prog1', '=', 'programmes')
                ->on('term_Year1', '=', 'ternYear');
        })
        ->where('programmes', $getProgramme)
        ->where('ternYear', $getYear)
        ->where('termDesc', $getTerm)
        ->where('level', $getLevel)
        ->get();
```

this is my view

```
  </tr>
                </thead>

                @foreach ($item->groupBy('groups') as $grouped)
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                        <td>{{$grouped[0]->groups}}</td>
                        </td>
                    </tr>


                    @foreach ($grouped as $row)
                    <tr>



                        <td>{{ isset($row->subject) ? $row->subject : '' }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $row->exams30 }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $row->exams70 }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $row->exams100 }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $row->subject_ranked }}</td>

                        <td>{{ $row->grade }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $row->remarks }}</td>
                        @endforeach

                    </tr>
                    @endforeach

                @endforeach
```

Comment: And what exactly are you struggling with?

Comment: I want to be able to obtained every student position by subject they offered by rank. Now i need to query with every subject on the row to obtained the position for that subject in the class

Comment: I don't quite understand, but either way, you're still only saying what you want. You're not stating what your problem is. What **specific** problem do you need help with?

Comment: How do i get the subject name of each row in the view to the controller for the query

Comment: You would need to create a `route` that takes a parameter, in this case the subject. The [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/routing#route-parameters) have plenty of examples.

Comment: It seems you dont understand my question, all i need to get subject name from the parent query and use it in the subquery for every iteration.

Comment: Or better still have an array of the subjects and where subject of the parent query is say English, the newsubject = "English" in that order in the subquery.

Comment: Sorry, I just don't understand what you're asking. Hopefully someone else does.